# SCSS variable export not imported in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

After a general package upgrade on my React project, SCSS variable imports in JavaScript stopped working. Imports themselves are still working, but variables exported from SCSS never appear in JavaScript.

Here's what I'm doing:

**_variables.scss:**

```
$akt-dark-teal: #035164;
$akt-light-blue: #007FAA;

:export {
    primaryMain: $akt-dark-teal;
    secondaryMain: $akt-light-blue;
}
```

**In React:**

```
import scss from './scss/parts/_variables.scss';

console.log(scss);                       //  [object Object]
console.log(scss.primaryMain);           //  undefined
console.log(scss.secondaryMain);         //  undefined
```

This used to work before the package upgrade. The path to the imported SCSS file is correct, I verified it. Besides similar exports fail the same way with other files, no matter where they are or what is their name.

I think the problem lies somewhere in the packages:

**The current `package.json`:**

```
{
    "name": "js-dashboard",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "homepage": "/public/",
    "dependencies": {
        "@date-io/moment": "^2.10.8",
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
        "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
        "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.1",
        "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.4.0",
        "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.13.2",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.10",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.1.5",
        "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.16",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "chart.js": "^3.1.1",
        "cryptr": "^6.0.2",
        "css-loader": "^5.2.4",
        "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
        "draftjs-to-html": "^0.9.1",
        "eslint": "^7.24.0",
        "firebase": "^8.4.1",
        "history": "^5.0.0",
        "html-react-parser": "^1.2.6",
        "http": "0.0.1-security",
        "https": "^1.0.0",
        "immer": "^9.0.1",
        "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
        "libphonenumber-js": "^1.9.16",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "material-ui-phone-number": "^2.2.6",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "nanoid": "^3.1.22",
        "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.0",
        "react-chartjs-2": "^3.0.2",
        "react-csv": "^2.0.3",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
        "react-to-pdf": "0.0.13",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",  
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "reselect": "^4.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.32.11"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "set PORT=3001 && react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.5.1"
    }
}
```

**The old `package.json` before the package upgrade:**

```
{
    "name": "js-dashboard",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "homepage": "/public/",
    "dependencies": {
        "@date-io/moment": "^1.3.13",
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
        "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.54",
        "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.0",
        "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.1.2",
        "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.11.0",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
        "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.11",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
        "cryptr": "^6.0.2",
        "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
        "draftjs-to-html": "^0.9.1",
        "eslint": "^6.6.0",
        "firebase": "^7.23.0",
        "history": "^5.0.0",
        "html-react-parser": "^0.14.2",
        "immer": "^7.0.15",
        "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
        "libphonenumber-js": "^1.9.4",
        "lodash": "^4.17.20",
        "material-ui-phone-number": "^2.2.6",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "nanoid": "^3.1.18",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.0.0",
        "react-chartjs-2": "^2.11.1",
        "react-csv": "^2.0.3",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
        "react-to-pdf": "0.0.13",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "reselect": "^4.0.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "set PORT=3001 && react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a fix for you but I'm working on a project in react and I wanted to import SCSS variables into react and after a couple of days I gave up. It'll be interesting to see what others have to say. Wondering if this is a bug in the newer react.js.

Comment: It very well may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update: fixed on CRA [v5.0.0](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v5.0.0)

---

This is a bug that appeared with the version 4 of `create-react-app`. [Here is the issue about it on Github.](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10047) It has been fixed since then and the fix should be available in the next release.

In the meantime, if you use something to override the webpack config of CRA you can fix it yourself by setting the `compileType` of `css-loader` to `'icss'` as explained in [this answer](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10047#issuecomment-774000223).

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately the glitch seems to persist in the latest version. This is what caused my trouble on the first place. So we wait...

Comment: Yep, the `icss` fix worked for me though.

Comment: The latest version seems to have fixed it.

Comment: @TamásPolgár Yes, I updated my answer.